# div set visible false from .net

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor

I need set visible false from c# but I don't know how can I do this.

This is my code:

```
if (mUserAgency == "011001")
{
    //ViewBag.Visibility = true;
    //ViewBag.myDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label">how can i set visible false</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="input-group m-input-group">
            <select id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="form-control m-select2 m-select2-general" style="width:100%">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With "HTML" I assume you mean "cshtml view"?

Comment: yess sir cshtml

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to just use `ViewBag.Visibility = true;`, `ViewBag.Visibility = false;` to store the visibility state. Then in the view, you can use the `ViewBag.Visibility` to add styling to the div:

Add new css class (you also could do it inline)

`.hidden
{
    display: none;
}`

`<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label" class="@(ViewBag.Visibility != null && ViewBag.Visibility == false ? "hidden" : "")">how can i set visible false</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="input-group m-input-group">
            <select id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="form-control m-select2 m-select2-general" style="width:100%">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

The advantage of doing it with a separate class is that you will be able to reuse it later. Also, it's just a better practice to keep css separated from views.

Comment: my div is not hidden sir

Comment: Try changing `display: none;` to `display: none !important;`